# Get array from scope changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my code, how to get name from array change in my inputbox???
How to get all my changed name in an all array??? Thank's in advanced. Marco.

app.js

```
var g[];
var names = ['John', 'Steve', 'Mark', 'George'];

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
  g.push({myCount: i, myName: names[i]});
};

$scope.allnames = g;

$scope.Calculate = function (??????) { 
   console.log(' INDEX = ' + myCount ???????);   
   console.log(' CHANGE NAME = ' + myName ???????);

};
```

index.html

```
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="testx in allnames">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="testx.myCount"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="testx.myName" ng-blur="Calculate(?????)" />
  </div>
```

Comment: First observation, the `i` variable in your `for` loop should start at `0` and stop at `<= 3` or you should rewrite `names[i]` to `names[i-1]`. Arrays are zero-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All changes to your model are stored in `$scope.allnames`, so, in order to `Caculate()` the values of the edited object, you need a reference to it. In this example, since the objects are stored in an array, the `$index` variable provided with `ng-repeat` gives us exactly what we need.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="testx in allnames">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="testx.myCount"/>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="testx.myName" ng-blur="Calculate($index)" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.Calculate = function (index) { 
  // get the associated object from $scope.allnames
  var person = $scope.allnames[index];

  console.log(' INDEX = ' + person.myCount);   
  console.log(' CHANGE NAME = ' + person.myName);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use $index to get index in ng-repeat

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="testx in allnames">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{testx.myCount}}"/>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="testx.myName" />
</div>
```

It works..!!